# Why I can't set state to Firebase's doc data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I fetch data from my firestore database like thus:

```
const [songs, setSongs] = useState();

async function getSongs() {
  const songs = collection(db, 'songs');
  const songSnapshot = await getDocs(songs);
  const songList = songSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
  setSongs(songList);
  console.log(songList);
  console.log(songs);
};
```

If I run this, there are two objects in the console, the first one is **songList**, and the second one is **songs**:

[image: console image here]

Why is there a difference between the two? What do I do to turn **songs** back into an array?

Comment: What error do you get? The code looks fine and should set songList

Comment: songList is an array, but when I set my "songs" state with songList, songs!=songList (see console image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"songs"` is a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference) and does not contain the data. `"songList"` is an array which contains data from the documents returned by `getDocs()`. You should set `songList` in your state instead of `songs`

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference),

> A CollectionReference object can be used for adding documents, getting document references, and querying for documents (using query()).

Comment: Thanks to your comment, I've realized the real (dumb, very dumb) problem! Turns out I use the name "states" for two different variables, one is the ColletionReference you said above, and the other is a State (first line in my code)